# Visual Studio 2008 Editor Configuration - Caret & Current Line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration

I am trying to do a couple of things to customize the Visual Studio 2008 Editor Configuration. I want to do this via some setting or macro that I can write myself. I can't install third-party add-ins such as resharper to achieve these goals in the environment where I work. Here is what I need to do:

1. I want to change the color of the
   caret in the editor to #FF0000
2. I want to change the background
   color of the current line where the
   caret is to a slightly darker shade
   than the rest of the editor window

I have searched the Visual Studio options extensively and I can't find settings for these specific things. I also looked into the object model that VS exposes to macros and no dice. Any pointer are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked into that before and found that there's no way to color the current line outside of an add-in.  A quick search indicates that the same is true of the caret/cursor as well.  Sorry.

Can you not run add-ins even if they are your own?  The necessary code is available, so you could probably build your own add-in that does just what you want.

http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2008/05/new-plugin-highlightcurrentlineineditor.html

http://dxcorecommunityplugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/HighlightCurrentLineInEditor/

Comment: I can definitely write my own add-ins, I just can't use a third party commercial product

Comment: Looking at the code I linked, it's pretty heavily tied into the DevExpress object model.  Unfortunately it won't be easy to extract that functionality into a stand-alone addin.  I don't have any experience with addins, so I can't really say how feasible it is.